# Chrome browser using allot of resources, Is there a "system monitor" feature for Chrome browser OSX?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser

Im using Chrome browser on a Mac computer running Big Sur OS.

In Big Sur OS, in the activity monitor chrome is taking most of the system resources even when ive only got a few browser tabs open.

Is there a "system monitor" type feature in chrome browser to allow me to see which tabs, plugins etc.. are using using the most of resources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a task manager built into Chrome (and all Chromium-based browsers). You can reach it via selecting `More tools` > `Task manager` from the menu or via pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> on Windows.

[image: image showing how open task manager in Chrome browser]

Comment: Shift + Esc may be the key combo for Windows only, I have no Mac with me at the moment so I cannot verify if it's the same for OSX as well.

Comment: There's no key command on Mac, but the tool is in the same place in the menu.

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer.